# Can't get this simple ng-submit to work

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS by working through [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gsJS5QgFT2IvWIX78dV3_v) on YouTube tutorial and I've hit a block on the 14th video with the ng-submit directive.

See code snipit below, when you fill in the form at the bottom and click submit it's supposed to add a new *Ninja*, but it's not working. There are no errors showing in the console. I placed a `debugger` breakpoint within the `addNinja()` function definition and it doesn't go into it when I click submit.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var myNinjaApp = angular.module('myNinjaApp',[]);

myNinjaApp.controller('NinjaController', ['$scope',function($scope){
 $scope.removeNinja = function(ninja){
  var  removeNinja = $scope.ninjas.indexOf(ninja);
  $scope.ninjas.splice(removeNinja, 1);
 };

 $scope.addNinja = function(){
  $scope.ninjas.push({
   name: $scope.newninja.name,
   belt: $scope.newninja.belt,
   rate: parseInt($scope.newninja.rate),
   available: true
  });
 };

 // $scope.addNinja = function() {
 //        $scope.ninjas.push(this.newninja);
 //        $scope.newninja = '';
 //    };

 $scope.ninjas = [
 {
  name: "Yoshi",
  belt: "green",
  rate: 50,
  available: true
 },
 {
  name: "Crystal",
  belt: "yellow",
  rate: 30,
  available: true
 },
 {
  name: "Ryu",
  belt: "orange",
  rate: 10,
  available: false
 },
 {
  name: "Shaun",
  belt: "black",
  rate: 1000,
  available: true
 }  
 ];
}]);
```

```css
body{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
}

h1,h2,h3{
  margin: 0;
}

.belt{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu-bar{
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu-bar h1{
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu-bar ul{
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

#menu-bar li{
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#menu-bar a{
  color: #fff
}

main{
  background: #eee;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content{
  padding: 20px;
}

.content button,
.content input[type="submit"]{
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(20,20,20,0.1);
  font-size: 16px;
}

.content button:nth-child(2){
  float: right;
}

.content ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.content li{
  padding: 15px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  color: #444;
}

.content li span{
  float: right;
}

.content li h3{
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.content input{
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.content input[type="submit"]:last-child{
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.remove{
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: crimson;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myNinjaApp">
<head>
 <title>TheNetNinja Angular Playlist</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="content">
  <div ng-controller="NinjaController">
   <button ng-click="order = 'name'">Order by Name</button>
   <button ng-click="order = 'belt'">Order by Belt</button>
   <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for a ninja">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="ninja in ninjas | orderBy: order | filter: search" ng-show="ninja.available">
     <h3>{{ninja.name}} - {{ninja.rate | currency: '£'}}</h3>
     <div class="remove" ng-click="removeNinja(ninja)">x</div>
     <span class="belt" style="background: {{ninja.belt}}">{{ninja.belt}} belt</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <form ng-submit="addNinja()">
   <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="newninja.name" />
   <input type="text" placeholder="belt" ng-model="newninja.belt" />
   <input type="text" placeholder="rate" ng-model="newninja.rate" />
   <input type="submit" value="Add new ninja">
  </form>
  <p>{{newninja}}</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a div in the wrong place - move `</div>` above `<form ng-submit="addNinja()">` to after `<p>{{newninja}}</p>`

bascially the ng-submit is not within the ninjacontroller div

see - https://plnkr.co/edit/pPucxMw0Yjr9OZoxl0vy?p=preview for a working version

Comment: thanks that makes perfect sense, it was outside the `div` with the `ng-controller` defined.

Answer (score 0):

myNinjaApp.controller('NinjaController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $http, $log) {

```
$http({
    url: "data/ninjas.json",
    method: "GET"
}).then(function (resp) {
    //$log.log(resp.data);
    $scope.ninjas = resp;
}, function (resp) {
    $log.error("ERROR Occurred");
    //debugger;
});

$scope.removeNinja = function (ninja) {
    var removeNinja = $scope.ninjas.indexOf(ninja);
    $scope.ninjas.splice(removeNinja, 1);
}

$scope.addNinja = function () {
    $scope.ninjas.push({
        name: $scope.newninja.name,
        belt: $scope.newninja.belt,
        rate: parseInt($scope.newninja.rate),
        available: true
    });
    $scope.newninja.name = "";
    $scope.newninja.belt = "";
    $scope.newninja.rate = "";
};

$scope.removeAll = function () {
    $scope.ninjas = [];
};

$scope.sort = function (keyname) {
    $scope.sortKey = keyname; 
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
}
```

}]);